# how to get standard output json in php

Tags: php, mysql, json

I want to get a JSON output like http://api.androidhive.info/json/movies.json and I wrote this code in PHP:

```
<?php
    $con=mysqli_connect("localhost","root","","ebrahim");
    $sql="SELECT * FROM movie";
    $result=mysqli_query($con,$sql);
    $response= array();
    while($row=mysqli_fetch_array($result,MYSQLI_NUM)){
        $product = array();
        $product["title"]=$row[1];
        $product["image"]=$row[2];
        $product["rating"]=$row[3]; 
        $product["releaseyear"]=$row[4]; 
        $product["genre"]=$row[5];   
        array_push($response,$product);
    }
    echo json_encode($response);
?>
```

but my output is like this : [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JxMt5.png)

Please help me to make a standard JSON.

Comment: Set your header properly `header('Content-Type: application/json');`

Answer (score 2):

I'm not exactly sure what you mean by "standard" JSON. Your output is already JSON. However, if you want to give the browser (or any other client) a hint about the content, set the proper content type. As Bart pointed out, this can be done by adding the appropriate header:

```
header('Content-Type: application/json');
```

Additionally, if you want the "nice" formatting of the JSON output, use the options parameter of [json_encode](http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-encode.php): The option [`JSON_PRETTY_PRINT`](http://php.net/manual/en/json.constants.php) should help to achieve that. So instead of `echo json_encode($response);` you should put

```
echo json_encode($response, JSON_PRETTY_PRINT);
```

into your script. `JSON_PRETTY_PRINT` is available since PHP 5.4.

Answer (score 2):

`echo json_encode($response, JSON_PRETTY_PRINT);`

Pass `JSON_PRETTY_PRINT` constant as the second parameter to the `json_encode` function.

Also, set content type of the response to JSON format with the following code:

```
header('Content-Type: application/json');
```

So, browsers recognize the response is a JSON resource.

Answer (score 0):

PHP has a function for it. Use JSON_PRETTY_PRINT you can read more about it [here](http://php.net/manual/en/json.constants.php)